# Error in Keras while doing Multi-class classification

Tags: python, keras, multiclass-classification

I am trying to do Multi-class classification in Keras. I am using the 
[crowdflower dataset](https://www.crowdflower.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/text_emotion.csv).Here is my code below:

```
import pandas as pd

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Flatten, Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder



df=pd.read_csv('text_emotion.csv')

df.drop(['tweet_id','author'],axis=1,inplace=True)


df=df[~df['sentiment'].isin(['empty','enthusiasm','boredom','anger'])]


df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

labels = []
texts = []


for i,row in df.iterrows():
    texts.append(row['content'])
    labels.append(row['sentiment'])

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)


sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index


print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))

data = pad_sequences(sequences)


encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(labels)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(labels)


labels = np.asarray(encoded_Y)


print('Shape of data tensor:', data.shape)
print('Shape of label tensor:', labels.shape)

indices = np.arange(data.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
data = data[indices]
labels = labels[indices]
print labels.shape


model = Sequential()



model.add(Embedding(40000, 8,input_length=37))

model.add(Flatten())




model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(data,labels, validation_split=0.2, epochs=150, batch_size=100)
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (9,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Can someone please point out the fault with my logic? I understand my question is kind of similar to [Exception: Error when checking model target: expected dense_3 to have shape (None, 1000) but got array with shape (32, 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335434/exception-error-when-checking-model-target-expected-dense-3-to-have-shape-non)

But I have not managed to find the bug.

Comment: what is your labels shape?

Comment: Don't use 40000 embedding layer dimension. Use like a 100 or 200.

Comment: @loannis Nasios (Shape of data tensor:', (38125, 37))
('Shape of label tensor:', (38125,))

Comment: @VikashSingh https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270546/how-does-keras-embedding-layer-work

Comment: Input should always one dimension as batch size (if batch is being used, And keras accepts None here) and the other dimension as the input feature width. in this case that will be number of words in padded sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making multiple mistakes in that code and I will suggest some improvements to make the code better:

1. remove: `for i,row in df.iterrows():` you can directly use

   ```
   labels = df['sentiment']
   texts = df['content']
   ```
2. While using `tokenizer = Tokenizer(5000)` set max words, this is vocabulary size.
3. When padding `data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=37)` provide max length.
4. Don't convert the output just to an array of values `labels = np.asarray(encoded_Y)`, it's not a regression. You have to one hot encode it:

   ```
   from keras.utils import np_utils
   labels = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
   ```
5. When providing the embedding layer `model.add(Embedding(40000, 8,input_length=37))` your vocab size is 40K and embedding dimension is 8. Does't make much sense as the data set you have provided has close to 40K unique words. which can't be all be given a proper embedding. `model.add(Embedding(5000, 30, input_length=37))` Change to a more sensible number vocab size. NOTE: if you want to use `40000` please update `Tokenizer(5000)` to the same number.
6. Use variables like `embedding_dim = 8`, `vocab_size=40000`. whatever the value might be.
7. Instead of `model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))` as final layer use this, keeps the code clean.

   ```
   model.add(Dense(labels.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
   ```

Final working code is attached at this [Link](https://pastebin.com/SPJTKe6Y)

Comment: One thing I would like to add is when you mention Tokenizer(5000), it creates a tokenizer configured to only take into account the 5000 most common words.

Comment: So effectively what you are doing is you are making this model by choosing a subset of the most frequently occurring 5000 words as opposed to the whole 40K words. I guess it reduces unwanted noise. By the way, great answer.